# How to add a new line to an existing text file in java?

Tags: java

I have used bw.newline and "n/n" but nothing seems to separate the lines when there is a new input.

```
try
{       
    FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter("transactions",true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write("Withdrawn"+ " "+withdraw+ "\r\n"+ "Balance" + " "+initialamount.get(Wd)+"\r\n"+
            " "+ date);

    bw.close();

}
catch ( IOException e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a PrintStream :

```
try(PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream("transactions"))
{       
    printStream.println();
    printStream.println("Withdrawn " + withdraw);
    printStream.println("Balance " + initialamount.get(Wd));
    printStream.println(date);
}
catch ( IOException e)
{
    //You should do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow the same type of structure and using a `FileWriter` and a `BufferedWriter` then you'll want something like the following:

```
try
{
    FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter("src/resources/test.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
    bw.write("Withdrawn: " + withdraw +"\n");
    bw.write("Balance: " +initialamount.get( Wd ) + date );
    bw.newLine();
    bw.close();
}
catch ( IOException ignored )
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the PrintWriter class?

```
FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter("src/resources/test.txt",true);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filewriter);
pw.println();
pw.println("Withdrawn " + withdraw);
pw.println("Balance " + initialamount.get(Wd));
pw.println(date);
```

It should handle the exceptions too